# Linear/Conditional navigation using a single button swiftUI

Tags: swift, view, navigation, swiftui

I would like to be able to navigate between views using 2 arrows and have an indicator of which page the user is on.

Currently, the page indicator is somewhat accurate (correct when i do load to a new page), however I am unable to have the navigation link work from within this struct.

The function is within its own file and is called in another view using `Foo(progress: Index)`

```swift
    var Index : Int = 1

    struct PageCounter: View {
    
        let progress: Int
        init(progress: Int) {
            self.progress = progress
        }
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { if Index > 1 { Index -= 1 } } ) {
                Image(systemName: "lessthan") }  
                Spacer()

                ForEach(1 ..< 8) {value in
                    if value-1 < self.progress {
                        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")                        
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                    }
                }

                Spacer()

                NavigationLink(destination: getDestination()) {                
                Button(action: { if Index < 8 { Index += 1 } } ) {
                Image(systemName: "greaterthan") } }
            }
        }

    func getDestination() -> AnyView {
        if index == 1 {
            return AnyView(View1())
        } else if Index == 2 {
            return AnyView(View2())
        } else if Index == 3 {
            return AnyView(View3())
        } else if Index == 4 {
            return AnyView(View4())
        }  else {
            return AnyView(MainPage())
        }
      }
    }
```

The indicator looks similar to this [image], clicking the arrows currently doesn't seem to do anything however

How can I get this to properly work? And is there a better way to achieve it than I am currently trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the progress and index struct states, then using a nav view with a tag and selector using the states makes it correctly navigate instead of hanging.

```swift
    struct PageCounter: View {
        
        @State private var progress: Int?
        @State private var index: Int = 1

        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: getDestination(), tag: index, selection: $progress) {
                Button(action: { if index > 1 { 
                    self.progress -= 1
                    self.progress = self.index } } ) {
                Image(systemName: "lessthan") }
```

Making the variables states and using the tag and selection arguments of the navigation link allow it to adaptively update based on the values rather than relying on an external refresh before taking action